# Mac OS X Terminal: -bash: $: command not found

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, command-line, bash

While trying to install pagekite on OS X Snow Leopard using the following command:

```
$ pagekite.py --signup
```

I got:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

I am a noob with the terminal but after reading a bit I understand that it is a problem with my PATH

```
echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Can anybody spot the problem? If you ask me -without knowing a thing about it- I suspect the MacGPG2 (MacGnuPrivcacyGuard2) is out of place?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you including the $? The command starts after that(`pagekite.py --signup`). The `$` is used to refer to the start of the prompt, but that does not mean you include it when you type commands.

Comment: Similar help can be found at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208425/5472

Answer (score 2):

Your PATH looks fine. The PATH variable is a collection of folders/directories in which the shell looks for commands to execute. So if you install additional software like MacGPG there might get new parts added.

But I assume that the command you are calling is called `pagekite.py` and not actually `$`. So you should call it like

```
pagekite.py --signup
```

or (if it is in your current folder/directory)

```
./pagekite.py --signup
```

The `$` is often used in documentation to represent the shell command prompt and should not be entered to run the command afterwards.