# OS X Terminal not recognizing any commands

Tags: terminal, bash

I recently tried to install CoffeeScript on my mac and now am unable to use even the most basic of commands like ls, cd and so on. Something tells me that it's because the $PATH variable has changed. I remember having to do that when I tried to make the installation. I tried following the instructions found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/), but it doesn't work because the vi command isn't found.

Upon entering echo $PATH in the terminal, it reads /usr/local/bin:

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in. Nothing you do to $PATH should be able to break it, so quite possibly you've done something much worse to your machine.

Comment: It is odd that `echo` works but `cd` and `ls` do not. Try opening Terminal preferences and making a new profile. Then make it run `bash --noprofile` and uncheck "Run in shell" (I think the options for this are in the Advanced tab). Also see if `type` or `which` work.

Comment: To add to the @Wooble correct analysis, I think that `cd` is working and you thought it didn't because of `ls` not usable. I advise you to double check this information and upgrade your original question to avoid people wanting to help you to hunt for a martian :).

Answer (score 4):

To reset your path, remove the line that sets the path from your ~/.bash_profile or equivalent, then reopen your Terminal.

Edit it with /usr/bin/nano, or /usr/bin/open, or TextMate, or any other text editor. It's not that no command can be reached, but that the PATH doesn't include these binaries—they can still be manually opened by providing the path or using cd to the directory.

Comment: Also, you can the path temporarily to test things before editing files that don't get read until you start a new session - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208425/5472

Answer (score 4):

You corrupted your `PATH` variable definition. Without any indication of which method you choosed to modify it, I will make the hypothesis that you
modified it within your `~/.bash_profile`.

To recover from this situation, you will have to come back to a working shell environment and then try to fix correctly and test your `~/.bash_profile`.

### Recovery of a working `~/.bash_profile`: none

Remove your `~/.bash_profile` and create a backup of it.
Since your `PATH` is not trustable, don't use it (use the full path of `mv`):

```
/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile.bak
```

Open a new `Terminal` window, within this one, every command should be
found. Check that you recovered a working `PATH`:

```
echo $PATH
```

If you find it easier, after this check, you could restart your session so
that any new shell will get a working PATH.

### Analyze what is wrong in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
grep PATH ~/.bash_profile.bak
```

### Fix and test it

Rather to fall back again with an unfunctionnal `PATH`, use the backup
file of your `~/.bash_profile` to fix it there it and test it.

To test it enter:
    . ~/.bash_profile.bak
    echo $PATH

### Put back in place the validated `/.bash_profile`

Once you are satisfied, and you checked you have access to all your
commands:

```
mv ~/.bash_profile.bak ~/.bash_profile
```

and if you want to use it immediatly without restarting your full session,
just enter:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you removed or didn't configure your `PATH` environment variable correctly. Try removing that line from ~/.bash_profile then open a new terminal window and verify that your paths are set correctly.

You don't have to use a command line text editor, you can use BareBones Software's excellent and free [TextWrangler](http://barebones.com/products/textwrangler/). This should reduce errors trying to figure out how vi works.

If you do not want to install another app, vi is located at `/usr/bin/vi`. For command line editors I would recommend pico over vi `/usr/bin/pico` which is much more user friendly than vi or emacs, but is clunky when compared to TextWrangler. Pico puts all of the relevant commands at the bottom of the editing window.

Good Luck!

Comment: You can use TextEdit.app which is part of OSX no need for TextWramgler