# Terminal command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew

So I was going thru RoR tutorial, installed heroku, heroku toolbelt. I got an error message from Heroku to update to newvest Git for safety reasons. I tried that with installer but heroku version didn't change.

I installed homebrew and tweaked the .bash profile $PATH and changed Git to use /usr/local/bin/git. Original was something like: /usr/bin/

I got some brainer and put gem update on terminal at one point and then inturreped it as
I didn't know what was going on.

Problem is know that terminal says either: command not found or No such file or directory || when I try to run something.

Because of that I can't even get the hidden files to show up. What should I do?

EDIT: when I run /bin/echo $PATH I get: /usr/local/heroku/bin
EDIT: Almost **** myself when commands very working but I I was able to run /usr/bin/open ~/.bash_profile -a  and comment out export route defined by Heroku

- Thank you

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208425/5472 for bash help with $PATH