# -bash: 1: command not found - Immediately on loading Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

Upon loading my terminal (since trying to install composer globally) I'm being spammed with countless amounts of -bash: 1: command not found before I even type any commands.

I'm not quite sure what to do, but this is all that happens, I load up terminal and get;

```
-bash: 1: command not found
-bash: 1: command not found
-bash: 1: command not found
-bash: 1: command not found
```

for an unlimited amount of times until I close the terminal.

Can anyone help me fix the issue, or reset my terminal, or anything?

---

Update:

Trying to run `rm -i ~/.profile ~/zsh* ~/.bash*` like advised in the comments I got the below:

```
-rm: ~/.profile: No such file or directory
-rm: ~/zsh*: No such file or directory
-rm: ~/.bash*: No such file or directory
```

I still get the ***command not found*** error.

Comment: What is in the bash startup files?

Comment: depends on your startup files, try running `rm -i ~/.profile ~/zsh* ~/.bash*` see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm going to put a hold on this. Let's see if the linked question gets you a resolution.

Comment: Specifically, the answer on http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208425/5472 about not editing or deleting anything. Just focus on fixing $PATH right now in one terminal. Once you have a sane cling the dot files or deleting them can happen to fix the root cause.