# When I open the terminal I get the error /Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/.zshrc:17: command not found: “export

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, big-sur, zsh

When I opened terminal today, I see this error

```
/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/.zshrc:17: command not found: “export.
```

All commands seem to work fine, it is just my inner perfectionest screaming.

I have M1 MacBook Air on Big Sur 11.2.3

.zshrc file:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/miniforge3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/miniforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/miniforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/miniforge3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

“export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/miniforge3/bin:/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/miniforge3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin”
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Is line 17 of your .zshrc file needed? Commenting it out might help or you’ll want to [check syntax of PATH before that line.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304322/5472) your edit command would be `/usr/bin/open ~/.zshrc -a TextEdit`

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotes before the word `export` and at the very end of the file. This should not be quoted at all, let alone in smart quotes.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the line should be `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` (and note that those *must* be plain double-quotes to work right). That way it'll properly take into account the other changes to `PATH`, rather than replacing them.

Comment: Does zsh PATH need a $PATH after the = in the export line?

Comment: @bmike That would be the usual best practice.  But not needed in this case because the line includes `/bin` etc. at the end.  There are other oddities, like two python3 frameworks with the old one first.  But who am to criticise - my `PATH` is pretty untidy too!